# Update all timestamps with minutely intervals

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data rows that include a StartTime (DATETIME) field. There is a row of data for every minute for approx the last year. I want a way to run a script to update the StartTime field so that the timestamps are 'recent' (this is demo data for a web app).

My idea was to use ROW_NUMBER() and DATEADD() to update each row with a new timestamp, starting with the current time a year ago, and iterating one minute per row.

The idea seemed to work for a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
DATEADD(MINUTE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by StartTime),DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())) AS Ds
FROM Test WHERE ItemId='0E0814B9-79A0-4BCF-AB33-B89D84CA3BEC' ORDER BY StartTime;
```

Which produces the expected timestamps separated by one minute:

```
2015-12-21 17:57:55.550
2015-12-21 17:58:55.550
2015-12-21 17:59:55.550
```

But when I try the same concept with an UPDATE statement:

```
WITH Datarows (Ds)
AS
( 
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by StartTime),DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())) AS Ds
    FROM Test
    WHERE ItemId='0E0814B9-79A0-4BCF-AB33-B89D84CA3BEC'
)
UPDATE Test 
SET StartTime = Ds
FROM Datarows
```

All the timestamps that are updated are then the same:

```
2015-12-21 17:30:14.463
2015-12-21 17:30:14.463
2015-12-21 17:30:14.463
```

Why is this not working? How can I update all the rows to have timestamps separated by one minute?

Comment: In your update, how are the tables related?  It looks like all rows in TEST will be updated with all values from the CTE, with only the last update being stored in the StartTime column.

Comment: @Steven Test is the only table (no relations). I want to update each row so each timestamp is different, separated in time by one minute.

Comment: What is the order for the TEST table to be updated?

Comment: @Steven the order should be by StartTime (preserving the existing order).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Steven is right - currently you are updating all rows in `Test` with last value in the CTE. You need to associate the row being updated in the `Test` table to its equivalent in the CTE:

```
WITH Datarows (TestId, Ds)
AS
( 
    -- Where TestId is the primary key of the test table
    SELECT TestId, DATEADD(MINUTE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by StartTime),DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())) AS Ds
    FROM Test
    WHERE ItemId='0E0814B9-79A0-4BCF-AB33-B89D84CA3BEC'
)
UPDATE Test 
SET StartTime = Ds
FROM Test t
INNER JOIN DataRows d
ON d.TestId = t.TestId
```

Answer (score 3):

@Steven correctly points out you have not explicitly defined the join between Datarows and Test.

@Strickt01 provides a nice example of how this can be achieved.

Here is an alternative syntax, that demonstrates you do not always need the [FROM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177634.aspx) clause when combining a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with an [UPDATE query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
WITH Datarows AS
    ( 
        SELECT
            StartTime, 
            DATEADD(MINUTE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by StartTime),DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())) AS Ds
        FROM 
            Test
        WHERE 
            ItemId='0E0814B9-79A0-4BCF-AB33-B89D84CA3BEC'
    )
UPDATE 
    Datarows 
SET 
    StartTime = Ds
;
```